# What is Bootstrapping in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, bootstrapping

What is Bootstrapping in Laravel and how does it work?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/lifecycle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bootstrapping is the process Laravel takes to combine the necessary bits in the framework together to be able to process and handle the functionality thrown at the system.

Inside the bootstrap folder you will find a few files:
`autoload.php` - loads and includes composer so any packages are loaded.
`services.php` - stores the providers in the application to load the system quicker.
`app.php` - loads and initialises the app.

As above, all of this is easily discoverable online.

Answer (score 18):

I will try my best to simplify Laravel's Bootstrapping process.
Some terms to understand before we focus on bootstrapping process:

### Necessary Terms

#### Service Container

Holds different components which can be used in your application

#### Facades

Laravel has lots of features and helpers. For example, helpers regarding URL, Response, Route, Session, Request, etc. These are loaded into the service container. Facades makes it possible to access these features without going through a service container and can be accessed directly.

#### Middleware

Middleware is a code executed on each request. For example, setting up the session. cookie encryption etc. Middleware is required by each request.

#### Service Providers

Service Providers are classes required by your application. These are not loaded on each request, but only when the service they provide is actually needed.

#### Kernel

The kernel is responsible for loading all the middleware, service providers

## The process

When a web page is requested, the request first goes to the **`index.php`**. This file does very important things. First, it autoloads all the classes used in your application.

After that, it sets up the Laravel application i.e. the Laravel framework. One of the first things the Laravel framework does is - creates the **service container**. At this point the service container is empty.

After that framework creates **Kernel**. Kernel loads all the **middleware** required by the application. One of the most important tasks of the Kernel, thereafter, is to load all the **service providers** i.e. to load all the components into the service container.

The list of all the service providers loaded is in the `config/app.php` file i.e. `'providers'` array. This array defines which components are loaded into your service container.

These components can be accessed via the **Facades**. The list of all facades is also present in the `config/app.php` as in the `'aliases'` array. These facades are simply shortcuts to all the components loaded into the service container.

This finishes the bootstrapping process.

After all these, the request is then handed over to the **router** i.e. `routes/web.php` file.

Comment: But isn't the bootstrapping process to costly since it's triggered with every request? In other words, a kernel class is spawned with each incoming user action?

Answer (score -1):

Before a request can be handled, certain dependencies or parts of the Laravel application have to be setup. These parts allow for the request to be processed as intended by the application, allowing as well for a response to generated appropriately. Bootstrapping is the process of setting all these things up.

In a bit technical terms as per [service providers documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/providers), "service providers" is the name that is used to refer to the different classes (chunked up pieces of code with a pre-defined outcome) that will be used to register and boot the required functionality for the Laravel application to work properly.